# Parent Child Process Communication in C through common file

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to write a program where child and parent process communicate through file reading and writing. Parent reads a file and increment by one and then child reads and multiply by 10. This code works for one time, but when I put the code in loop to do the calculation 5 times it doesn't work. any help would be appreciated. I am trying to do it with `open()` `read()` `write()` `close()` `wait()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    int f;
    int f1;
    int x;
    char buff;
    int value = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
            printf("fork failed");
            return 1;}
        if (pid>0)
        {   
            f = open("input.txt", O_RDWR);
            while ((x = read(f, &buff, sizeof(buff))) > 0)
            {
                write(1, &buff, 1);
            }
            int value1 = atoi(&buff);
            value = value1;
            close(f);
            //printf("Parent Number Before: %d\n", value);
            value++;
            char tmp[i];
            sprintf(tmp,"%d", value);
            //printf("Parent Number After: %s\n", tmp);
            f = open("input.txt", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC);
            write(f, tmp, strlen(tmp));
            close(f);
            wait(2);
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            f = open("input.txt", O_RDWR);
            while ((x = read(f, &buff, sizeof(buff))) > 0)
            {
            }
            //printf("Buffer: %d\n", buff);     
            int c = atoi(&buff);
            //printf("Child Number Before: %d\n", c);
            c = c * 10;
            char tmp[i];
            sprintf(tmp,"%d", c);
            //printf("Child Number After: %d\n",c);
            close(f);
            f = open("input.txt", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC);
            write(f, tmp, strlen(tmp));
            close(f);
            return 0;
        } 
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The desired out put is

> Parent : 1
>
> Child : 10
>
> Parent: 11
>
> Child : 110
>
> Parent : 111
>
> Child : 1110
>
> Parent : 1111
>
> Child : 11110
>
> Parent : 11111
>
> Child : 111110

Comment: Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This will be tricky with files. Try a pipe instead (since you're forking the child) or a named pipe.

Comment: Minor point, but at the end of the child you should call `_exit(0)` instead of returning. This is required to skip `atexit` hooks and global destructors

Comment: "wait(2)"? Read the manpage for wait more carefully (and in general - check the return value of any syscall like open, wait etc, and perror() if you get unexpected results)

Answer (score 0):

Other than the `wait`, which occurs after you've done all the work, you have no synchronization between the processes, so they will be reading and writing the file at the same time, which easily leads to files filled with nothing but garbage.

You need to use either advisory file locks (`flock(2)`, `lockf(3)`, or `fcntl(2)` with `F_SETLK`, `F_SETLKW`, and `F_GETLK`; read the man page for differences) or IPC semaphores (`sem_overview(7)`)

Answer (score 0):

Neither file locking nor semaphores will easily obtain the alternating sequence you desire.

Conceptually, you need to pass a "token" between the two processes. Whichever process has the token can proceed and then pass the token to the other process.

One could use two different signals (USR1 and USR2 spring to mind) and signal handlers to accomplish this.

One could also use a pipe between the processes: each process could write to the pipe (while the other process is blocked in a read) to pass the token. This solution would likely require less coding than the signal solution.